# Why requests table having duplicate operation_id in application insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I would like to ask why Operation_Id is duplicate in Requests table.
or what is proper configuration of Application Insights so telemetry will be unique based on opeartion_id ?

requests
| where operation_Name contains "GetFuelPriceAsync"

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type of app are you instrumenting? Did you add an SKD? Are you generating the telemetry yourself using the SDK?

Comment: Here's an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#example) that I think it can prove operation_id can be duplicate at least. And I [guess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-request-telemetry#id) 'id' is the unique property.

Comment: azure app service – Peter Bons

Comment: requests
| where operation_Name contains "GetFuelPriceAsync" and operation_Id in ("Dt3IfYfSbRw=")

only request table having duplicate operation id , but you have referred with joins with multiple tables - @Tiny-wa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every request/dependency telemetry item has the following identifiers:

1. `operation_Id` is unique per distributed transaction. So it is by design not to be unique per request
2. `id` is unique per telemetry item
3. `parent_Id` points to a parent's telemetry item `id` in a distributed transaction identified by `operation_Id`

This is based on default behavior of applications instrumented with Application Insights SDKs.

If your web app is also instrumented with JavaScript Application Insights SDK then it starts a transaction per web page. If this web page does multiple calls to your app service then requests originated from the same web page will have the same `operation_Id`. If your web page is SPA then the current default behavior is that whole session will be treated as one transaction.